# C++ Opengl with SDL2_image texture showing white only

Tags: c++, opengl, sdl-2, texture-mapping, sdl-image

I'm trying to display a spinning cube with 6 different textures (all jpg and jpeg) using SDL library. But the program only shows white squares only. Anyone can please explain what happened to these textures?

each function behavior

`opengl_init()`: init opengl settings

`init()`: init SDL settings including opengl_init()

`clean_up()`: runs right before program ends

`RenewTexture()`: here I want to map texture with this function

`main()`: about drawing vertexes and playing each frame with spinning function

```
const int window_width = 1024;
const int window_height = 1024;
const int SCREEN_BPP = 32;

SDL_Event event;
SDL_Window* win = NULL;
SDL_Renderer* renderer = NULL;
GLuint texId[6];
SDL_GLContext context;
/****** Name Space for Game Variables ******/
namespace var
{
    int frame_start_time = 0;
    int frame_current_time = 0;
    int frame_count = 0;
}

/****** Initializes Core OpenGL Features ******/
bool opengl_init()
{
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glDepthFunc(GL_LEQUAL);

    glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
    glEnable(GL_BLEND);
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

    glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluPerspective(45.0, (640.0 / 480.0), 0.1, 100.0);

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();

    std::cout << glGetError << std::endl;
    if (glGetError() != GL_NO_ERROR)
    {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}


/****** Initializes SDL, OpenGL and Video and Window ******/
bool init()
{

    //if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING) < 0)
    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) < 0)
    {
        return false;
    }

    win = SDL_CreateWindow("WINDOW", 100, 100, window_width, window_height, SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL);
    renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(win, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED);
    context = SDL_GL_CreateContext(win);

    if (opengl_init() == false)
    {
        return false;
    }
}

/* Removes objects before game closes */
void clean_up()
{
    SDL_Quit();
}

void RenewTexture(SDL_Surface* tmpimg, int index) {
    GLubyte* map = (GLubyte*)tmpimg->pixels;

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texId[index]);
    int w, h;
    w = tmpimg->w;
    h = tmpimg->h;
    /*glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexEnvi(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_REPLACE);*/
    glTexImage2D(
        GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB,
        w, h, 0,
        GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,
        map
    );
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
//  glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texId[index]);
}

int main(int argc, char* args[])
{
    std::vector<SDL_Surface*> image;
    GLfloat rotation = 0.0f;

    bool quit = false;

    if (init() == false)
    {
        return 1;
    }

    const char* ImageNames[6] = { "res/KGU-logo.jpg", "res/Me.jpeg", "res/beach-1838501.jpg", "res/bench-560435.jpg", "res/wolf-1341881_1920.jpg", "res/spring-bird-2295434.jpg" };
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        SDL_RWops* tmprwop = SDL_RWFromFile(ImageNames[i], "rb");
        SDL_Surface* tmpimg = IMG_LoadJPG_RW(tmprwop);
        image.push_back(tmpimg);
    }

    for(int i=0;i<6;i++)
        glGenTextures(1, &texId[i]);

    /*SDL_Rect position;
    position.x = 1;
    position.y = 1;
    position.h = 10;
    position.w = 10;
    SDL_RenderClear(renderer);
    SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(renderer, image.at(0)), NULL, &position);
    SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);*/

    /****** Main Game Loop ******/
    while (quit == false)
    {

        /****** Get Most Current Time ******/
        var::frame_start_time = SDL_GetTicks();

        /****** Draw Rectangle ******/
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
        glLoadIdentity();
        glTranslatef(0.0f, 0.0f, -6.0f);
        glRotatef(rotation, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);


        RenewTexture(image.at(0), 0);
        glBegin(GL_QUADS);
        glTexCoord2f(0.0, 0.0); glVertex2f(0, 0);
        glTexCoord2f(1.0, 0.0); glVertex2f(550, 0);
        glTexCoord2f(1.0, 1.0); glVertex2f(550, 550);
        glTexCoord2f(0.0, 1.0); glVertex2f(0, 550);
        glEnd();

        RenewTexture(image.at(0), 0);
        glBegin(GL_QUADS);
        /* Cube Top */
        //glColor4f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
        glVertex3f(-1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
        glVertex3f(-1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f);
        glVertex3f(1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f);
        glVertex3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
        RenewTexture(image.at(1), 1);
        /* Cube Bottom */
        //glColor4f(1.0f, 0.5f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
        glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);
        glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);
        glVertex3f(1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);
        glVertex3f(1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);

        RenewTexture(image.at(2), 2);
        /* Cube Front */
        //glColor4f(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
        glVertex3f(-1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
        glVertex3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
        glVertex3f(1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);
        glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);

        RenewTexture(image.at(3), 3);
        /* Cube Back */
        //glColor4f(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.5f, 1.0f);
        glVertex3f(-1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f);
        glVertex3f(1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f);
        glVertex3f(1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);
        glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);

        RenewTexture(image.at(4), 4);
        /* Cube Left Side */
        //glColor4f(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 1.0f);
        glVertex3f(-1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f);
        glVertex3f(-1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
        glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);
        glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);

        RenewTexture(image.at(5), 5);
        /* Cube Right Side */
        //glColor4f(0.15f, 0.25f, 0.75f, 1.0f);
        glVertex3f(1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f);
        glVertex3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
        glVertex3f(1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);
        glVertex3f(1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);

        glEnd();

        rotation -= 0.5f;
        /****** Check for Key & System input ******/
        while (SDL_PollEvent(&event))
        {

            /******  Application Quit Event ******/
            if (event.type == SDL_QUIT)
            {
                quit = true;
            }
        }

        /****** Update Screen And Frame Counts ******/
        SDL_GL_SwapWindow(win);
        var::frame_count++;
        var::frame_current_time = SDL_GetTicks();

        /****** Frame Rate Handle ******/
        if ((var::frame_current_time - var::frame_start_time) < (1000 / 60))
        {
            var::frame_count = 0;
            SDL_Delay((1000 / 60) - (var::frame_current_time - var::frame_start_time));
        }
    }
    clean_up();
    return 0;
}
```

**Edit**

Solved via changing all `glTexCoord3f()` to `glTexCoord2f()` and it worked... my fault :D

additionaly, I misunterstood `glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_3D)` so changed to `glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D)`, and checked all opengl errors via error check function

```cpp
void errorcheck() {
    int errormsg;
    if ((errormsg = glGetError()) != GL_NO_ERROR)
    {
        std::cout << "glerror: " << errormsg << std::endl;
        exit(0);
    }
```

}

Comment: You need to call `glColor` and `glTexCoord` for every vertex. Furthermore, your `RenewTexture` function re-uploads the image on *every frame* instead of once. Finally, you are using the deprecated immediate mode. If you are learning OpenGL you should use the modern shader-based approach. See [open.gl](https://open.gl) and [learnopengl.com](https://learnopengl.com)

Comment: thank you for the advice Botje, so I changed those parts. but still having hard time with the texturing. Searched too much time and resulted in 3 parts I could make mistakes. The settings of Glut and SDL, or sequences of method usage, or the images themselves. (as I'm not using power of 2 images, so I tried to change them but nothing seems changed).